# Unable to save a jpeg image at the client end

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, fs

I have an image stored at the server end. Whenever client connects to the server, it sends the image through sockets. The received image I am able to display it on canvas, however I am unable to save the received image in the local disk. I am trying to use fs.writeFile(), but maybe I am not sending the right parameters. Any leads to this issue will be helpful. Thank You. [I want implement this as a basic communication client-server].

To optimize it, is there any way can I achieve same operation in a much faster way? Any working code would also he helpful.

```js
//server side js code

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var fs = require('fs'); // required for file serving

http.listen(6969, function(){
  console.log('listening on port 6969');
});


// trying to serve the image file from the server
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  start = new Date().getTime();
  console.log(start);
  console.log('a user connected');
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, buf){
    socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
    console.log('image file is transmitted');
  });
});
```

```html
<script>
var socket = io("http://139.25.100.101:6969");
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas_win').getContext('2d');
var fs = require('fs');
socket.on("image", function(info) {
  if (info.image) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + info.buffer;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = end; 
 fs.writeFile('logo.jpeg', img.src, 'data:image/jpeg;base64,', function(err){
       if (err) throw err
       console.log('File saved.')
  
})
}
});
```

Comment: nodejs and browsers javascript have different apis. (eg.: `document`, `fs`, ...)

Answer (score -1):

I am very new to this but I think that for a "communication" between 2 entities, both must be able at some point to act as server, hence thenecessity of a php script on both ends.

Clients usually send requests to be processed by the server, so if you need a p2p communication, the client must download a php script to enable it to act as a server....

Again, I am a newbie so I might be (VERY) wrong